# Boost binary serialization format specification

Tags: c#, c++, sql-server, serialization, boost

Yes, I know, serialized data produced by boost is intended only for the library internal use and not to be read by third parties. However I find myself in a position that I have to mimic binary serialized data originated from .NET (std::vector of tiny PODs) which would be deserialized later by boost (C++ native). CLI/C++ interop with native boost is not possible since the assembly have to be CLR pure.
Is it feasible? just to write the right sequence of bytes? Is there any binary format spec? I didnt find any.

EDIT001: Some background: I have a table in a database, hundreds of millions of rows. each row consists of two IDs - entity ID, parent entity ID and additional column for entity data (all entity data in the form of JSON, but it doesnt matter, I cant change it). Now, in the native C++ I have to select entities by parent ID to get all entities it has, it would yield (sometimes) 5M rows, as one can guess it will take ages to query, receive, iterate, parse and load into vector of C++ structs. So I've tested what if I have my own table with parent ID as PK and a column with all entities belonging to that ID binary serialized. The result (aside data transfer over network, etc) I can parse (actually, boost can) it in ~400ms which is not blazing fast but good enough for me. Now, how do I get my table populated with binary data? Obviously DBA team cant help here, they know nothing about boost binary format, so I resorted to CLR user defined function which MUST be implemented as "pure" CLR. this UDF is supposed to be called from stored procedure which populates table with individual entities and in the end will run over these and create binary bulk. But how I can mimic the boost binary format if I cant call boost (CLI/C++) in my assembly???

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly, that you feel this is the best solution?

Comment: will update the question